# How do I collapse the gaps in my table style?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I have to build via code, because it's representing grouped data from a query based on a person's name.  So person xyz has 4 rows of data... My question is simply how do I style this for each group alternating in color?

Here's what I have so far and it works, but there's gaps on the sides, top and bottom of each cell, I want the color for the groups to be solid.... no gaps...  I've given the table rows and td the class name of alternate for the ones to be colored..alternate

```
tr.alternate{background-color:#aaa;}
td.alternate{background-color:#aaa}
```

Comment: For layout issues, it would be a good idea to post your markup and styles so you can get a verifiable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `border-collapse: collapse` in your table.

> The border-collapse CSS property selects a table's border model. This
>   has a big influence on the look and style of the table cells.
>
> The separated model is the traditional HTML table border model.
>   Adjacent cells each have their own distinct borders. The distance
>   between them given by the border-spacing property.
>
> In the collapsed border model, adjacent table cells share borders. In
>   that model, the border-style value of inset behaves like groove, and
>   outset behaves like ridge.

**source:** [border-collapse developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)

Example without `border-collapse`:

```css
tr.alternate {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="alternate">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="alternate">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example with `border-collapse`:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr.alternate {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="alternate">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="alternate">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see you don't need separate class for `td`.